# how do specfiy :with attribute in rails 3 link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is link_to_remote code for rails 2.3.8

> link_to_remote "Click here",
>            :update=>'flowtracker',
>              :with=>"'topcount='+$('topcount').value,
>             :url=>{
>              :controller => 'sessions',
>              :action     => 'session_for_tracker',
>              :layout=>1
>             }

link_to_remote deprecated in rails 3
so how can i specify the :with attribute in **link_to** rails 3
And i'm using prototype.js

Comment: I can't see :width anywhere, I think they have probably removed it.

Comment: See this link http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote

Answer (score 0):

Use `link_to` helper with `:remote => true` option and do whatever you want in your js view file to your action.

**EXAMPLE**

in view:

```
<%= link_to 'ajax call', :controller => "sessions", :action => "session_for_tracker", :remote => true %>
```

in controller:

```
def session_for_tracker
  @topcount = 1000; #get actual value here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

in js view for action:

```
page << %|
  $('flowtracker').update("#{@topcount}");
|
```

Comment: I'm new to rails 3 .. so can you give some examples?

Comment: Updated answer, check example.